# Output Cookie value into html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

Im trying to implement some cookies on my website. Ideally I would like to save the user html form input into cookies so that it is automatically set for later reference. However this form also sends the values to the database, like so:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<?php

if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
    $errorMessage = false;

    if(empty($_POST['formName'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage = true;
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formEmail'])) 
    {
$errorMessage = true;       }
    if(empty($_POST['formAddress'])) 
    {
$errorMessage = true;       }
if(empty($_POST['formPrice'])) 
    {
$errorMessage = true;    }


$varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];
    $varAddress = $_POST['formAddress'];
$varPrice = $_POST['formPrice'];
    $varComments = $_POST['formComments'];

     if($errorMessage == false) 
    {

     $db = mysql_connect("","","");
  if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
  mysql_select_db("" ,$db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO formdata (name, email, address, price, comments) 
VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($varName) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varEmail) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varAddress) . ", " .
          PrepSQL($varPrice) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varComments) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);

        header("Location: thankyou.php");
        exit();
    }
}

//sql injection protection..
function PrepSQL($value)
{

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }


    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>        
<body>

<div class="Formm">
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    if ( $errorMessage == true ) {
        echo( "<h3>PLEASE FILL IN ALL QUESTIONS WITH A STAR.</h3>" );

    }


    $result = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT * FROM `formdata` WHERE user=$user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1" );

    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
        // output data of each row
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
            $id = $row[ "id" ];
            $varname = $row[ "varname" ];
            $varemail = $row[ "varemail" ];
            $varaddress = $row[ "varaddress" ];
            $varprice = $row[ "varprice" ];
            $varcomments = $row[ "varcomments" ];
        }
    }

    ?>
    <p>

        <label for='formName'>Venue name*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varName); ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='formEmail'>Email*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formEmail" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varEmail);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formAddress'>Address*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formAddress" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varAddress);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formPrice'>Estimated price*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formPrice" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo($varPrice);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formComments'>Any comments associated with the Venue that the artist should be aware of?</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formComments" maxlength="250" value="<? echo($varComments);?>"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>




<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>


</body>
</html>
```

NEW EDITIm trying to implement some cookies on my website. Ideally I would like to save the user html form input into cookies so that it is automatically set for later reference. However this form also sends the values to the database, like so:

Comment: there isn't enough code here and you mention a database; the question's unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry about that, hope this edit clarifies things up a bit

Comment: I noticed the edit: there is no cookie code anywhere. The less we know, the more time it takes, remember that. I will now have to pass on this one and let someone else look at your post.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Understood. It's just that I have not enough knowledge on how to implement this. Hope this pseudocode kinda ish helps.

Comment: I would recommend reading over [W3School's page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) on cookies for javascript. If you are still having problems then update your question with what code is not working for you. Your question currently shows no code or effort of what you have tried for setting the cookies, so it can come across as "can someone write my cookie code for me?" even if that was not your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your database for this. Make a script that get's the last entered data from the user and place it in the form

Example:

```
//query
$result = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT * FROM `formdata` WHERE user=$user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1" );

if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    // output data of each row
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        $id = $row[ "id" ];
        $name = $row[ "name" ];
        $email = $row[ "email" ];
        $address = $row[ "address" ];
        $price = $row[ "price" ];
        $comments = $row[ "comments" ];
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This fits your need:

```
<div class="Formm">
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    if ( $errorMessage == true ) {
        echo( "<h3>PLEASE FILL IN ALL QUESTIONS WITH A STAR.</h3>" );

    }


    $result = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT * FROM `formdata` WHERE user=$user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1" );

    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
        // output data of each row
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
            $id = $row[ "id" ];
            $varname = $row[ "varname" ];
            $varemail = $row[ "varemail" ];
            $varaddress = $row[ "varaddress" ];
            $varprice = $row[ "varprice" ];
            $varcomments = $row[ "varcomments" ];
        }
    }

    ?>
    <p>

        <label for='formName'>Venue name*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varName); ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='formEmail'>Email*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formEmail" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varEmail);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formAddress'>Address*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formAddress" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varAddress);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formPrice'>Estimated price*</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formPrice" maxlength="100" value="<? echo($varPrice);?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='formComments'>Any comments associated with the Venue that the artist should be aware of?</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="formComments" maxlength="250" value="<? echo($varComments);?>"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer this seems to be exactly what I am looking for! I however wonder how to exactly implement this into the code. Youre saying to place this code in <?php ?> code at the start of the form?

Comment: Place this before the output of the html form and print/echo the variables to the form fields

Comment: I edited my code a bit in the main post, could you please further assist me of printing these values into the fields it doesn't seem to work, forgive my lack of knowledge. Thank you

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, i Will when i come home

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jeroen i have added the code in my edited answer

Comment: Wow perfect! This however just echos $varname and all the other variables in the input fields instead of the content they should be holding. I posted my full code if that might help. Saying <?php makes the echo in the field go away but it doesnt seem to do the trick either. Thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: @Jeroen try Google your Way to find out What suits you situation